# Memory leak in Chrome with Websockets

Tags: websocket

We are streaming binary data from our server via websockets to web browsers.
The browser receives the data just fine; we can manipulate it with Javascript.

The code is a very basic one:

```
   function WebSocketTest()
   {
        if ("WebSocket" in window)
        {
           var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3456/someresource");

           ......

           ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
           { 
              //var received_msg = evt.data;
              //var reader = new window.FileReader();
              //...........
           };

           ..............................................
           ..............................................
```

The problem is - even in this simplest form (onmessage function is all empty, so we do nothing with evt.data, which is a binary blob), the memory usage of Chrome browser keeps growing, as if garbage collector never frees the blob. It grows forever until Chrome closes websocket connection or crashes. We have tried to manually release evt.data with various methods, but nothing helps. You would expect that the code above will not cause memory leak in Chrome, correct? How to release the blob referenced by evt.data?

Comment: Please do not post commented or uncommented sequences of dots instead of actual code. Please take the time to design and implement [the exact shortest code sample that reproduces your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What? Consider sequences of dots non-existing. The problem happens with just the code you see, nothing else.

Comment: Oh, I see. My apologies, please remove the dots and close your curly braces, then. And please read the link I posted, you never know.

Answer (score 2):

Hey I have found the reason for "memory leak" - it's not a memory leak but my programming error. Posting here just in case anyone else makes the same mistake. What happened is - for messages larger than 64KB you need to format the data length as a 64-bit integer packaged in network byte order. I was not converting my Windows-based __int64 to network byte order correctly. So the browser thought it's downloading a huge message (10GB or something like that) - and kept downloading until run out of memory.

Comment: can you please help me to solve problem?