# Why does memory used constantly increase in my simple Javascript websocket application?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, websocket

I am having a problem with websocket in Javascript.
Memory consumption is increasing constantly and I just don't understand why.

My websocket server sends out around 1KB of data per second and it seems like the memory consumed is increasing at the same rate.

If I open up Chrome task manager I can see that the memory consumed by my tab increase constantly. It seems to be the same problem with Internet Explorer.

I have based my code on the example found at this page: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm

This problem seems to be somewhat similar, but I still don't understand what the problem is. 
[Memory leak in Chrome with Websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689162/memory-leak-in-chrome-with-websockets)

What am I doing wrong?

Refreshing the web page do release the memory but there must be another way...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var systems = {};
     function WebSocketTest()
     {
        if ("WebSocket" in window)
        {

           // Let us open a web socket
           var ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.1:8081/websocket");

           ws.onopen = function()
           {
              // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
              var subscribe = {};
              var request = {};
              request["test"] = "1";
              subscribe["subscribe"] = request;
              ws.send(JSON.stringify(subscribe));
              //alert("Message is sent...");
           };

           ws.onmessage = function (evt)
           {
              var received_msg = evt.data;
              var obj = JSON.parse(received_msg);
              var samples = obj.samples;
              delete samples;
              delete obj;
              delete receieved_msg;

           };

           ws.onclose = function()
           {
              // websocket is closed.
              alert("Connection is closed...");
           };

           window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
              socket.close();
           };
        }

        else
        {
           // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
           alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
        }
     }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <a href="javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
  </div>
  </body>
  <script>

  </script>
  </html>
```

Comment: [`delete` does not do what you think it does](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/). Omit those lines. (Not that it would help anything)

Comment: As garbage collector can't be enforced, what you may need to do for variables that are not going out of the scope but are not needed anymore is set them to NULL instead of using `delete`.

Comment: I tried to set evt.data, obj, samples and received_msg to null. Good to know how to do it but the problem is still there.

Comment: Any news on this? How do you destroy a WebSocket instance?

Comment: I think I solved this by automatically reloading the web page once every day.